# Directories ending with dots behave strangely on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filenames

Recently I noticed a strange directory whose name is `foo.`. When double-clicking it to view its content, I found it to be identical to `foo`. I then deleted `foo` and tried to view `foo.` again, but Windows Explorer said it not found. If I attempt to delete `foo.`, `foo` is gone instead. Refreshing Explorer, rebooting will not erase `foo.`, and raw disk browser still shows it's there. Also `RD foo.\` cannot remove `foo.`, but `foo` as well.
I'm curious about this "trailing dot mechanics". Can anyone explain its strange behavior?

Comment: What windows version are you using, and is this folder located on your harddrive or a network location? In windows 10, a folder with . is treated as if it is without

Comment: @LPChip I tried to find out but it seems to make no difference across XP, 7 and 10. It's on an NTFS volume.

Answer (score 4):

In windows, the . character is a separator for extensions. When you have a folder, by default, it has no extension. A folder ending with a period basically is the same, a folder with no extension.

Although they both show up, internally they are referred as the same. So deleting one will delete both, but explorer is not smart enough to understand that which is why you still see it. If you want a folder that ends with a ., add a space behind the dot. Do note, the space has to be ALT+255. That way, a folder has the extension space and as such it is different, while by appearance it will look the same.